# need help finding syntax error HDLCompiler:806

Tags: vhdl

I have been trying to get these if statements to work but I cant get rid of a syntax error.

this is the error I'm getting:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Lab_7/control.vhd" Line 34: Syntax error near "=".
>   ERROR:ProjectMgmt - 1 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.

```
entity control is
    port (
        opcode : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        alu_src : out std_logic;
        alu_op : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    );
end entity control;

architecture main of control is

    begin

        process(opcode)

        begin

        if opcode = "0100" then 
        alu_src <= "1";

        elsif opcode = "0101" then
        alu_src <= "1";

        elsif opcode = "0000" then
        alu_src <= "0";

        elsif opcode = "0001" then
        alu_src <= "0";

        elsif opcode = "0010" then
        alu_src <= "0";

        elsif opcode = "0011" then
        alu_src <= "0";

        else 
        alu_src = '0';

        end if;

    end process;

end architecture main;
```

Comment: Besides the double quotes for character literals the else assignment to alu_src is malformed (the = should be <=). I'd suspect that's line 34 from the original (and you could mark your example code with a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You are using double quotes with std_logic signals. Use single quotes as you did it for the else statement.